# Why does setting my Directories or Resources not save?

Tags: civicrm.settings.php

On some sites Civi gives users a warning about 'Directory Paths: Make them portable' and the warning directs them to the Directories page to fix them.

The user makes the changes and saves them, but may find the System Status warning remains - so they go back and look in Directories and guess what, the changes have not been saved

Why does this happen and what can be done to reduce the frustration of this?

Answer (score 1):

The changes are not being saved because the settings are being overridden by civicrm.settings.php

To improve this we have made a [PR](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21777) to help clarify to the user what is happening by providing a pop up message saying "Fields Inputs loaded as 'readonly' as they have been set (overridden) in civicrm_settings.php"

Comment: This has now been added to 5.x